# Code works well on macOS and doesn't work on iOS (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

Code below works well on macOS (Catalina 10.15.3 at least), but same code (just copy-paste) doesn't work on iOS Simulator (13.2.2/13.3) and Xcode 11.3.1 preview (app just crashes). Can someone explain me, what I'm doing wrong?

The problem is here: `.onAppear(perform: self.initView)` (on updating `users` property), but I don't know, what is wrong.

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var users = [User]()
    var body: some View {
        List(users, id: \.id) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }.onAppear(perform: self.initView)
    }

    func initView() {
        self.users = [User(name: "test")]
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: No crash with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: Confirm crash with Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3 on Simulator (in Preview there is no crash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very informative part of generated crash log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view
>   after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained
>   in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

so it means there is some misalignment in update of table data (ie, actually, during reload data), in such cases, just by experience, there is reason to postpone performed action... and, it works in this case as well.

Here is a fix (or workaround, whatever) that works. Tested with Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3

```
func initView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // postponed update till next event cycle
        self.users = [User(name: "test")]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and clean explanation what to do. But I'm wondering, why my code above works on macOS without postponing...

Comment: The only problem left is that preview doesn't update when code changes (Xcode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3). But on simulator it works without crash. Is it possible to fix or preview isn't designed to work with postponing?

Comment: @Mikk, static Preview does not track async changes, but it works in LivePreview.